# Can't understand wrong answer in graphing program

Tags: c++

There is a problem in which they have points on a graph (~100 of them) and they all rotate by a certain amount, except one of them. I thus tackle this problem by taking the distances from the center of the first set of points, and also distances from center of the second set, then, after comparing them, one set will not have a matching distance--which will be the wrong point.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int star1, star2;
cin>>star1;
int x1[star1], y1[star1];
for (int i=0; i<star1; i++)
{cin>>x1[i]>>y1[i];}

cin>>star2;
int x2[star2], y2[star2];
for (int i=0; i<star2; i++)
{cin>>x2[i]>>y2[i];}

int d1[star1], d2[star2];
for (int i=0; i<star1; i++)
{d1[i]=sqrt(x1[i]*x1[i]+y1[i]*y1[i]);
 d2[i]=sqrt(x2[i]*x2[i]+y2[i]*y2[i]);
}
int dis=0; //the ones furthest from the center will be gone

if (star1>star2)
 {for (int i=0; i<(star1-star2); i++)
 {if (d1[i]<d1[i+1])
 {dis=i+1;} }

 for (int i = dis; i < star1; i++)
{d1[dis] = d1[dis+1];
d1[star1-1] = 0;}
}

 else if (star2>star1)
 {for (int i=0; i<(star2-star1); i++)
 {if (d2[i]<d2[i+1])
 {dis = i+1;} }

for (int i = dis; i < star2; i++)
{d2[dis] = d2[dis+1];
d2[star2-1] = 0;}
 }

int one, two;
for (int begin=0; begin<star1; begin++)
{ 
for (int i=0; i<star2; i++)
 {if (d1[begin]==d2[i])
 {one=begin; two=i;
 goto finish;}}
  }
  finish:
  cout<<one<<" "<<two;
  }
```

The original problem: http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/wandering-star
Is it something wrong with my code, or something wrong with my interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see with you approach is you are assuming that the point of rotation is the origin. What if the set has been rotated about a different point?

Also, it seems to me that the prompt at the link you posted says the second image is a slight rotations *and a slight shift* from the first. This would imply that the point of rotation could be different in both sets. Also, note that the problem statement suggests a star near the edge may leave the image space. This case would need consideration.

Try thinking about how to find the point of rotation in each image. What properties does it have, and are there any ways you can use geometric properties to isolate it? If you were able to get both points of rotation, you would be able to proceed similarly to your suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
int d1[star1], d2[star2];
```

The size of the `d2` array is `star2`.

```
for (int i=0; i<star1; i++)
  {if (d1[begin]==d2[i])
```

The inner loop, `i`, iterates from 0 to `star1-1`, but the size of the `d2` array is `star2`.

This appears to be the bug. This should probably be:

```
for (int i=0; i<star2; i++)
  {if (d1[begin]==d2[i])
```